# What is the purpose of 并 in 他虽然并不聪明， 可是很努力?

Tags: usage, vocabulary

I have a sentence that I can't quite grasp the meaning of. The sentence is:

> 他虽然并不聪明， 可是很努力。

It's an example from a Mandarin Chinese textbook I'm using, teaching the usages of 虽然 ~ 可/但(是).

I ran the sentence through a translator and it means "Although he is not smart, he works very hard." My question is, what does the 并 mean here?

My understanding is that if it's used as a verb it means "to combine" and if used as an adverb it means "also, simultaneously, etc."

Also, would the sentence

> 他虽然不是聪明， 可是很努力。

be equivalent to the one above? The second sentence makes more sense to me intuitively.

Comment: 他虽然不是聪明， 可是很努力。: sounds wired. try removing 是

Comment: see previous question with answer by same author What does “他并没有来北京” means? What does 并没有 refers to?

Comment: 他虽然并不聪明， 可是很努力 doesn't sound really good. I prefer 他虽然不聪明， 可是很努力.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 並/并 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/844/
>
> [3] [adv] (used before a negative for emphasis) actually; definitely; really

~

> 他虽然**不**(not)聪明， 可是很努力。
>
> 他虽然**并不**(actually not)聪明， 可是很努力。

Other example of 并 as an adverb before a 'negative':

無(doesn't have) --> 并無 (actually doesn't have)

未(have not/ not yet)--> 并未 (actually have not/ actually not yet)

沒 (doesn't have/ did not)--> 并沒 (actually doesn't have/ actually did not)

*並 in '並有'(also have) or '並已'(had also) means 'also' since  有 and 已 are not negative*

> '並' 不一定 等於 '並且' ('並' does not always equal 'and also')
>
> '並' 并不一定 等於 '並且' ('並' actually does not always equal 'and also')

Answer (score 1):

并 (at negations) = (not) at all

> 他虽然**并**不聪明， 可是很努力。
>   Although he's not clever **at all**, he's very diligent.